# Circular cursor covers the text

Tags: html, css, gsap

I'm creating a circular cursor, and when it overlaps with the text, I want it to have the white background, but to leave the text. Now, however, it covers the text. I tried using z-index but nothing happened.

my html:

```
    <div class="cursor">

    </div>

    <section class="hero-text">
        <div class="hero-text-content">
            <h1 class="cursor-scale">Привет!</h1>
            <h2 id="hi">That's how we say 'Hi' in Russian</h2>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/main.js"></script>
```

my css:

```
.hero-text {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    cursor: none;
}

.hero-text h1 {
    font-size: 8vw;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-image: linear-gradient(132deg,
        #3ff4af 0%, #d8e614 100%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.hero-text h2 {
    font-size: 5vw;
    color: black;
    display: inline-flex;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid pink;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform-origin: center center;
}

.grow {
    transform: scale(10);
    background: white;
    /*mix-blend-mode: difference;*/
    border: none;
}
```

my js:

```
function elementsOverlap(el1, el2) {
    const domRect1 = el1.getBoundingClientRect();
    const domRect2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect();
  
    return !(
        domRect1.top > domRect2.bottom ||
        domRect1.right < domRect2.left ||
        domRect1.bottom < domRect2.top ||
        domRect1.left > domRect2.right
    );
}

var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor'),
    cursorScale = document.querySelectorAll('.cursor-scale'),
    hi = this.document.querySelector('#hi'),
    
    mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0

gsap.to({}, 0.016, {
    repeat: -1,

    onRepeat: function() {
        gsap.set(cursor, {
            css: {
                left: mouseX,
                top: mouseY
            }
        })
    }
})

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX
    mouseY = e.clientY
})

cursorScale.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        cursor.classList.remove('grow');
        cursor.classList.remove('grow-small')
    });
    link.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
        cursor.classList.add('grow');
        if (link.classList.contains('small')) {
            cursor.classList.remove('grow');
            cursor.classList.add('grow-small')
        }
    })
})
```

my result:
[image]

I'm doing it from the tutorial, and there they use mix-blend-mode: difference, but what I need is that when the cursor is white, it reveals the black text (`<h2>`), but when the mix-blend-mode is used, the text is white, so I decided to delete this property, but now the cursor is overlapped.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

`mix-blend-mode: difference;` makes sense over here.

[image: demo]

***Is this not what you require? Please specify what you're looking for.***

---

From what I understood from the description, you want the h2 text to only be visible within the large cursor.

In that case, `clip-path` might help.

Alternatively, adding `invert filter` with `mix-blend-mode` gives this result.

```css
.hero-text h2 {
  color: white;
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.grow {
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

[image: demo]